# Lodash .clone and .cloneDeep behaviors

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, lodash

I try to clone an array of objects with nested objects.

Something like:

```
var data = [
    { id: 1, values: { a: 'a', b: 'b' } },
    { id: 2, values: { c: 'c', d: 'd' } }
];
```

## _.Clone

With the [`_.clone`](http://lodash.com/docs#clone) method and the `isDeep` parameter at `true`:

```
var clone = _.clone(data, true);

data[1].values.d = 'x';

console.log( _.isEqual(data, clone) ); // true, clone[1].values.d == 'x'
```

I expected `clone[1].values.d == 'd'` :

> If isDeep is true nested objects will also be cloned, otherwise they
>   will be assigned by reference.

What is wrong?

## _.CloneDeep

In addition, when I try with the [`_.cloneDeep`](http://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) method, I get an error:

```
var clone = _.cloneDeep(data);

// Uncaught TypeError: Object function u(n){return n instanceof u?n:new o(n)}
// has no method 'cloneDeep'
```

Why this error?

## $.extend

With [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) the clone has no reference to the original object as expected:

```
var clone = $.extend(true, {}, data);

console.log( _.isEqual(data, clone) ); // false, clone[1].values.d == 'd'
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling the lodash version of clone and not the underscore version? I get the same behaviour as you describe if i add lodash.js first followed by underscore.js.

Comment: If I use the code in the question and assign lodash to `_`, I cannot reproduce the problem stated in the question. (That is, `_.clone` with `isDeep` set to `true` works as expected.) Gruff Bunny's hypothesis is a good one. I believe there's also a way to use lodash as an exact drop-in replacement for underscore.js. I'd expect such use of lodash to not perform deep copies since underscore.js does not do it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Thanks to Gruff Bunny and Louis' comments, I found the source of the issue.

As I use Backbone.js too, I loaded a special build of Lodash compatible with Backbone and Underscore that disables some features. In this example:

```
var clone = _.clone(data, true);

data[1].values.d = 'x';
```

- [with the Normal build](http://jsfiddle.net/u2Ufk/): `_.isEqual(data, clone) === false`
- [with the Underscore build](http://jsfiddle.net/U4MTL/): `_.isEqual(data, clone) === true`

I just replaced the Underscore build with the Normal build in my Backbone application and the application is still working. So I can now use the Lodash .clone with the expected behaviour.

**Edit 2018:** the Underscore build [doesn't seem to exist anymore](https://lodash.com/custom-builds). If you are reading this in 2018, you could be interested by [this documentation](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Migrating) (Backbone and Lodash).

Comment: Did you use underscore and lodash together?

Comment: No, Lodash replaces Underscore.