# _.extend vs _.clone in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

To inherit properties of one object by another while dealing with JavaScript objects, I often see usage of `_.clone` where the intention was to create an object with another object's properties and then it would be extended.

Why can't we just use `_.extend` which is more relevant to extend an object?

Please tell me the difference between the two and why we can't `_.extend` instead of `_.clone` which is a costly operation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851974/lodash-clone-and-clonedeep-behaviors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_.extend` mutates the object. `_.clone` creates a copy by *values*, not by *reference* and does not change the original object. Please note that `_.extend` is merely an alias for `_.assignIn`.

> `_.assignIn(object, [sources])`
>
> **Note**: This method mutates `object`.
>
> https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#assignIn

Also see documenation for `_.clone`:

> https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#clone

Comment: _.extend mutates the actual object and _.clone returns a copy of the object. Rather, why can't we establish a parent-child (prototypal inheritence) relationship between the objects so that, if the child doesn't have a property, it will inherit from parent and provide. And by doing so, we can have so many childs and a parent rather than mutating/cloning the object. Please tell me.

Answer (score 4):

If you `_.extend()` an existing object, **you mutate the object**. If you `_.clone()` it first, the original object remains untouched.

You could of course extend an empty object with the original object's properties and some additional ones, which also leaves the original object unchanged:

```
_.extend({}, originalObject, {
    additionalProperty: "foo"
})
```

This works very similar to a shallow clone of `originalObject`. With ES2015, you can achieve the same goal with plain JavaScript and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

---

Additional reading:

- [Why is immutability important in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34385684/3836229)

Comment: _.extend mutates the actual object and _.clone  returns a copy of the object. Rather, why can't we establish a parent-child (prototypal inheritence) relationship between the objects so that, if the child doesn't have a property, it will inherit from parent and provide. And by doing so, we can have so many childs and a parent rather than mutating/cloning the object. Please tell me.