# How to avoid JSON pointer in JavaScript with do not use json.stringify?

Tags: javascript, json, pointers

I want to copy employee to a new employee and not point to an old employee.
I try to use:

```
newEmployees.assign([{}].employees); <br>
newEmployees = [{...employees}]; <br>
```

They are pointing to an old employee.

```js
const employees = [
    {
        "id": "1001",
        "firstname": "Luke",
        "lastname": "Skywalker",
        "company": "Walt Disney",
        "salary": "40000"
    },
    {
        "id": "1002",
        "firstname": "Tony",
        "lastname": "Stark",
        "company": "Marvel",
        "salary": "1000000"
    },
    {
        "id": "1003",
        "firstname": "Somchai",
        "lastname": "Jaidee",
        "company": "Love2work",
        "salary": "20000"
    },
    {
        "id": "1004",
        "firstname": "Monkey D",
        "lastname": "Luffee",
        "company": "One Piece",
        "salary": "9000000"
    }
];

let newEmployees = [{}];
newEmployees[0] = employees[3]; // assign
employees[3]['firstname'] = 'Arhus'; // change old employees
console.log(newEmployees); //firstname: 'Arhus' - shows employees content
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) while assigning the value like this

```js
const employees = [
    {
        "id": "1001",
        "firstname": "Luke",
        "lastname": "Skywalker",
        "company": "Walt Disney",
        "salary": "40000"
    },
    {
        "id": "1002",
        "firstname": "Tony",
        "lastname": "Stark",
        "company": "Marvel",
        "salary": "1000000"
    },
    {
        "id": "1003",
        "firstname": "Somchai",
        "lastname": "Jaidee",
        "company": "Love2work",
        "salary": "20000"
    },
    {
        "id": "1004",
        "firstname": "Monkey D",
        "lastname": "Luffee",
        "company": "One Piece",
        "salary": "9000000"
    }
];

let newEmployees = [{}];
newEmployees[0] = { ...employees[3] };
employees[3]['firstname'] = 'Arhus'; // change employee
console.log(newEmployees); //firstname is still Monkey D
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.map` and object spread:

```js
const employees = [
    {
        "id": "1001",
        "firstname": "Luke",
        "lastname": "Skywalker",
        "company": "Walt Disney",
        "salary": "40000"
    },
    {
        "id": "1002",
        "firstname": "Tony",
        "lastname": "Stark",
        "company": "Marvel",
        "salary": "1000000"
    },
    {
        "id": "1003",
        "firstname": "Somchai",
        "lastname": "Jaidee",
        "company": "Love2work",
        "salary": "20000"
    },
    {
        "id": "1004",
        "firstname": "Monkey D",
        "lastname": "Luffee",
        "company": "One Piece",
        "salary": "9000000"
    }
];
const newEmployees = employees.map(employee => ({...employee}));
employees[3].firstname = 'Arhus';
console.log(newEmployees[3]);
console.log(employees[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

While assigning value you can use `Object.assign` or `Object.clone`

Consider the following snippet:

```js
 const employees = [
        {
            "id": "1001",
            "firstname": "Luke",
            "lastname": "Skywalker",
            "company": "Walt Disney",
            "salary": "40000"
        },
        {
            "id": "1002",
            "firstname": "Tony",
            "lastname": "Stark",
            "company": "Marvel",
            "salary": "1000000"
        },
        {
            "id": "1003",
            "firstname": "Somchai",
            "lastname": "Jaidee",
            "company": "Love2work",
            "salary": "20000"
        },
        {
            "id": "1004",
            "firstname": "Monkey D",
            "lastname": "Luffee",
            "company": "One Piece",
            "salary": "9000000"
        }
    ];
    
    let newEmployees = [{}];
    newEmployees[0] = Object.assign({}, employees[3]);
    employees[3]['firstname'] = 'Arhus';
    console.log(newEmployees);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to copy the object value and don't want to use stringify. Stringifying the object and parsing it back to JSON is one way,
cloning the object is another method and I believe spreading also works.

But if you prefer convenience you may want to take a look at "lodash" library's _.clone and _.clonedeep methods.

Also if you'd like to read more refer :

[Lodash .clone and .cloneDeep behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851974/lodash-clone-and-clonedeep-behaviors?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[How to copy an object by value, not by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624165/how-to-copy-an-object-by-value-not-by-reference?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)